# PHP, MYSQL - Token-based Authentication: what if someone stole my token?

Tags: php, jwt

I try to understand if I understand the using of "token-based auth" right.
For example, assume I have a login form and I want to authenticate a user.
The system is based on HTML, PHP & MySQL database.

The proccess:
1. The user type username & password and send them to the server.
2. The server (PHP) check in 'users' table in database if the details are correct.
3. If the details are correct, the server creates a secret token and insert it to 'auth_token' table in database.
4. The secret token saved in a cookie and the user pass the token every HTTP request to get access.

Until here, everything is fine.
But what if a third-party factor, like hacker, succeed to steal the token cookie from the user?
Then the hacker will get full access to the user account.
Am I right? If I right, so how it can be prevented? If it can possible anyway...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you cannot fully prevent someone from intercepting an auth token. (Some versions of that type of attack are known as a [Replay Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack)). However, there are things you can do to *mitigate* the damage that can be done if someone does manage to steal a token (and these are probably things you've noticed being done on other sites).

One simple thing that is done is that the site will ask the user to re-validate before they do anything too serious.  E.g. you may be asked again for your password before changing your email or password. Although the attacker may have stolen your token, it's less likely that they also know your credentials (especially if the site uses 2-factor authentication), so you can lessen the amount of damage that can be done by prompting users to re-authenticate before certain critical steps.

For more secure systems, the token is updated after each request so that it cannot be replayed. This is more work for the application because it has to validate the incoming token and then sign and return a new token for each request/response.  The catch is that if an attacker is able to steal your token and they submit a request *before* you do, then their request will be accepted and YOUR request will fail (!) because to the server, your request will look like the copy-cat.  If that were to happen, however, you could log back in and hopefully boot any other tokens logged into your account (more about that next).

Some web apps will show you how many auth tokens have been issued for your user.  Google does a good job of this: you can review other logins on other devices (usually along with some info about the user agent and IP address location), so it's easier for you to notice if there's a strange token in there, and the important thing is that it lets you log out those other tokens.

There are also "fuzzier" protections which can be accomplished by application-level firewalls.  They may do things like evaluate the IP addresses or user agents of the requests, and if the "same" user suspiciously sends the same token from 2 vastly different IP addresses or browsers, the firewall may log an error or take some other sort of preventative action.

Comment: Thanks! I though about an idea to pass the token in every request via PHP cURL (post or get). The idea is to pass the token in cURL request and get respone. This way I don't have to save the token in a cookie and I can't see a way to a hacker to find the secret token (in the only case the token need to be used until the user exit the browser of the tab of the website). Am I right? Thanks again!

Comment: You will *always* have to send the token in every request and response (remember: the web is stateless). When you send the token as a cookie, you are simply sending it in an HTTP header dedicated to cookies (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers#Cookies).  

It makes no significant difference from a security standpoint if you send the header in some other custom header or as a URL parameter: if a hacker is sniffing your traffic, assume they can see your full requests/responses and their headers.